# Centering a nested div

Tags: html, css

I have been searching on google and stack overflow for a while, but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to center a div within a div, which is all contained within a page wrapper. I can get it to center horizontally, but not vertically. Any suggestions?

I have tried display:inline-block with vertical-align:middle, but it had no effect.

CSS

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#page-wrapper {
  padding: 0 12.5% 0 12.5%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you OK with using `display: flex`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)  (There are dozens of duplicates of this question.  If "nothing seems to work" with the many answers already available, please be clearer about what specifically is different about your situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

change

```
#inner {
  position:relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:grey;
}
```

to

```
#inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:grey;

  /* magic here */
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

You could:

A. Change the height to be a specific number and add `margin-top: -`height`;`

OR

B. Add this into the code for the `#inner`

```
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Example of B: [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/2cheeky4you/pen/rYJQMm)

OR

C. If you want to make it fancy use a flexbox (instructions here: [Flexbox complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) and add:

`display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using flexbox, together with `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

Have a look at this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOQwre

Comment: Thanks for the response!